# Unable to scroll (MS Project Professional 2013)

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I'm unable to scroll quickly in my project file and need to select all tasks and copy so I can paste in an Excel file.  Is there a quicker way or key strokes to select all and copy?

Comment: Hi Dana, welcome to PMSE. Have a look on the [tour] page to see, how this site works and how to get best responses for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your project file, put your cursor in one of the lines within the spreadsheet-like project sheet. Press Ctrl-Home (should bring you to the first line), then Ctrl-Shift-End to select all lines towards the bottom of the file. From there, you can copy/Ctrl-C and paste into Excel or other destinations.

Comment: Hi Dag. Welcome to PMSE and thanks for answering. I know this seems like a really basic question/answer but it's always useful to provide a bit more info/context with your answers.

Comment: I hope it looks better now!